# Is batch deletion a better way to perform a directory delete in Azure storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to delete a directory (Or just a batch of blobs for that matter - I am aware of the fact that Azure storage do not have the consept of directories or folders) using c#. Right now I'm using parallel deleting (using Parallel.ForEach) of all the blobs in a folder - takes about a minute for 420 blobs that are summing up to 11 MB.

The code looks something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(urisToDelete.Distinct(), uri => { 
    var blobReference = await this.cloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(uri);
    await blobReference.DeleteAsync();
});
```

I am trying to optimize this process and I came across [this Microsoft's ducumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbatch.deleteblob?view=azure-dotnet) of batch deleting. It's a bit complicated to change it in my project for performance testing. Does anyone know if the performance is better using this method of deletion? Does anyone know a better method?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `batch deletion` via [batch client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch) provides a higher performance than using `Parallel.ForEach(xxx)`.

Since the `batch delete` will batch multiple Azure Blob Storage delete operations in a single request, which indeed has a higher performance. But when using `Parallel.ForEach`, it will send many requests and result in a lower performance.

But you should know the limitation when use it, like one batch only supports up to 256 subrequests etc. You can read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch#remarks) for more details about it.

As far as I know, this is the best way in performance to delete multi-blob-files.